# Highscore showing unexpected values

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a 2D top-down puzzle game. I am currrently having a little problem saving the high score. My game score system works like this:

`scoreCount` decreases when time (seconds) increases. The resultant decreased `scoreCount` will be added to a base score which is set to 100. That score will then be saved as high score if the `score > highscore`. In my case, the high score should be 0 at the beginning. The problem is that the high score at the beginning is showing a random number of 3099 (I've tried resetting the `PlayerPrefs` using `PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll();`). Here is my score manager script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ScoreManager : MonoBehaviour {
  public Text scoreText;
  public Text BestScoreText;
  private float score;
  public float scoreCount; 
  public float pointsPerSecond; 

  // void start()
  // {
  // 
  //
  // }

  void Update () {
    scoreCount += pointsPerSecond * Time.deltaTime;
    score = 100;
  }

  void FixedUpdate() {
    score = score + scoreCount; 
    scoreText.text = "Your Score : " + Mathf.Round (score);
    BestScoreText.text = "Best Score : " + ((int)PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("BestScore"));

    //PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll ();

    if (score > PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("BestScore")) {
      PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("BestScore", score);
    }
  }
}
```

And another thing: whenever I increase the `scoreCount`, the default best score increases. For example, if I set it to 10, the best score shows as 249; 100 means 1699, 200 means 3099. What mistake have I made?

Comment: Since BestScore is a float, why are casting it as an int? `((int)PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("BestScore"))`

Comment: One thing i can think you should try is instead of delete playerprefs is to set BestScore to 0

Comment: Just to be sure, but any reason you put back your score to 100 in your Update and not just set it in your Start function? I might have misunderstood what you are trying to achieve with your score there.

Comment: You might also want to update your PlayerPrefs "BestScore" before modifying the corresponding text value on screen. It's probably not the problem, but it seems more logical. You can do both in the same if statement, so that you don't update your text every `FixedUpdate`.

Comment: I think this is entirely due to the `score = score + scoreCount;` line in `FixedUpdate()`, if `FixedUpdate()` runs twice between two `Update()` runs (possible at low frame rates) then `score` would be equal to... `100 + scoreCount + 100 + scoreCount + Time.deltaTime`.

Answer (score 0):

You should set everything to `0` or `"0"` at the start of the game again. Otherwise it would start off with your previous settings I guess. If you delete your PlayerPrefs while your `score > 0`. Then It will set the PlayerPrefs equal to score again.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ScoreManager : MonoBehaviour {
  public Text scoreText;
  public Text BestScoreText;
  private float score;
  public float scoreCount; 
  public float pointsPerSecond; 

  void Start()
  {
    BestScoreText.text = "0";
    scoreText.text = "0";
    scoreCount = 0;
    score = 0;
  }

  void Update () {
    scoreCount += pointsPerSecond * Time.deltaTime;
    score = 100;
  }

  void FixedUpdate() {
    score = score + scoreCount; 
    scoreText.text = "Your Score : " + Mathf.Round (score);
    BestScoreText.text = "Best Score : " + ((int)PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("BestScore"));

    if (score > PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("BestScore")) {
      PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("BestScore", score);
    }
  }
}
```

I think this is the solution, but I haven't tested it, so sorry if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

## Use a local variable.

I suspect that `FixedUpdate()` is getting called twice between two `Update()` frames, resulting in the undesired value, as it would effectively double the actual score (previous score value, plus itself again, plus some deltaTime).

We can fix that by using a *local* variable instead of the one that gets modified from frame to frame.

```
  void FixedUpdate() {
    float scoreCheck = score + scoreCount; 
    scoreText.text = "Your Score : " + Mathf.Round (scoreCheck);
    BestScoreText.text = "Best Score : " + ((int)PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("BestScore"));

    //PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll ();

    if (scoreCheck > PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("BestScore")) {
      PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("BestScore", scoreCheck);
    }
  }
```

Mind, I think there are still-better ways of designing the game than this, as right now there's nothing that prevents scores from going below 0, PlayerPrefs is effectively stored in plaintext, which means that a user could hack their highscores (if they so desired), among other things.

But per the question asked, this is the solution.